# How to run tasks/promotions on jenkins pipeline builds?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, promoted-builds, hudson-plugin-batch-task

Does anyone have a mechanism to simulate what the promoted builds plugin does or the batch tasks plugin does, but for pipeline builds?

I want to be able to for example, run the maven release plugin after a build, or as the promoted plugin allows, "promote" a build.

The best case scenario would be that the promoted builds plugin or the batch task plugin would take a pipeline as input...

Or possible allow me to call another job (optionally) once a build is finished - but then I would want that job to run on this result.

Answer (score 0):

You can define pipelines at promotion time with this plugin :

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin

Comment: please help me with how to do that.. I can't see that facility anywhere.  On my pipeline build in jenkins there is no option to add a promotion and when I look at the options for promote I can't see anything to do with pipelines...

Comment: Once the plugin is installed in jenkins you can configure pipelines to have the option "Promote builds when ..."
There you can define criterias, and actions